# How can I get all data out of a MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, join

Some of my data is not coming out, in this statement. Specifically those where `retaurant_id = 0`. Is it because, it has nothing to compare with in my `entry_id`?

**MySQL**

```
"SELECT em.*, t.*, cd.*, ct.*, emd.*
FROM exp_members as em
Inner JOIN transactions as t on (em.member_id = t.cardid-10000000)
Inner JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
Inner JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
inner join exp_member_data as emd on em.member_id = emd.member_id
WHERE em.member_id = '".$_GET['cardid']."'"
```

**Current output**

```
Rest_navn   City        Postcode
San Remo    Roskilde    4000
```

**Desired output**

```
TransID    Rest_navn    City          Postcode
4214       San Remo     Roskilde      4000 
4212       0            0             0
4211       0            0             0
```

Ass you can see there is more data that has to come out; but it wont come out.

I already tried changing the `where` statement but nothing happened.

Some of my data is not coming out in this statement. Specifically those where `retaurant_id = 0`.

Is it because `t.restaurant_id = null` in this line?

```
Inner JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
```

And it has nothing to compare with in my `entry_id`?

Comment: Try left join to see if you get output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` -- it won't return 0, but will return NULL --  you can use `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` to return 0 if needed:

```
"SELECT em.*, t.*, cd.*, ct.*, emd.*
FROM exp_members as em
   LEFT JOIN transactions as t on (em.member_id = t.cardid-10000000)
   LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
   LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
   LEFT join exp_member_data as emd on em.member_id = emd.member_id
WHERE em.member_id = '".$_GET['cardid']."'"
```

To get 0 as the values instead of NULL, something like this should help (not sure about your table structures)

```
SELECT COALESCE(Rest_navn,'0')
```

Comment: Arrhh of course, thanks @sgeddes. It works fine now, i will accept your answer in 11 minutes

Comment: @Zaz -- np, glad I could help.

Comment: Note, returning `0` when you really mean `null` is often a horrible idea.  :P  Generally when you feel the need to do this, what you really need is to handle your data properly instead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I saw that too -- but it's somewhat negated by the WHERE clause.  Hence the reason I used it as the seed.  An Inner Join would work just the same or moving the WHERE criteria to the JOIN and using transactions as the primary.  Not completely sure without table structures.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want outer joins, starting with the transaction table:

```
SELECT em.*, t.*, cd.*, ct.*, emd.*
FROM transactions as t
     left outer JOIN exp_members as em on (em.member_id = t.cardid-10000000)
     left outer JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on (t.restaurant_id = ct.entry_id)
     left outer JOIN exp_channel_data as cd on (ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id)
     left outer join exp_member_data as emd on em.member_id = emd.member_id
WHERE em.member_id = '".$_GET['cardid']."'"
```

The first join, between `transactions` and `exp_members` could be written as an inner join, because the `where` clause will eliminate the extra records brought in by the outer join.  However, I think that keeping all the joins the same and starting with the table where you want all the record is the safest approach.